# Angular 8 getRole is not a function in nested object

Tags: angular, angular-http, ngoninit

I have an API, that returns me the `Profile` info and I am fetching it in my HTTP service. The nested object `User` has a method `getRole()`. But when I am trying to call this method, I get

> ERROR TypeError: _co.profile.user.getRole is not a function

When I fetch `User` from my other service, that only returns the `User` entity, I am able to call this function no problem.

What am I missing ?

**Model**

```js
export class Profile {
  user: User;
  apiKeys: ApiKey[];
}

export class User {
  user: string;
  firstname: string;
  surname: string;
  email: string;
  role: Role;
  active: boolean;

  getRole() {
    switch (this.role) {
      case Role.READ: {
        return "READ";
      }
      case Role.WRITE: {
        return "WRITE";
      }
      case Role.ADMIN: {
        return "ADMIN";
      }
      default : {
        return "READ";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**ProfileService.ts**

```js
getProfile(): Observable<Profile> {
    return this.http.get<Profile>(this.profileUrl).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

**Component.ts**

```js
profile: Profile;
isProfileAvailable:boolean = false;

ngOnInit() {
  this.settingsService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
    this.profile = profile;
    this.isProfileAvailable = true;
   });
}
```

**Component.html**

```html
<p-fieldset [legend]="Profile" *ngIf="isProfileAvailable">
    <div><b>User: </b>{{profile.user.firstname}}</div>
    <div><b>E-mail: </b>{{profile.user.email}}</div>
    <div><b>Role: </b>{{profile.user.getRole()}}</div>
</p-fieldset>
```

Comment: Please, give some feedback on our answers. thank you!

Comment: @Blauharley I've been busy these days, but I will try your solutions ASAP and give you the feedback.

Comment: Please, give some feedback.

Comment: @Blauharley Sorry for waiting so long, I finally had time to have a look at your solution. Thank you very much, it worked !

Comment: You are welcome. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `http.get<Profile>` does not automatically initialize an object of type `Profile`, therefore the property `user` is also not an object of type `User` and has not got the method `getRole`.

You can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to initilize objects and it's properties. And because there are two class types (`Profile`, `User`), both can extend from a `Base`-Class to handle the assignation of the properties for both types.

**Models:**

```js
// Use a Base class to assign all properties with objects both of type Profile and User
class Base {
    constructor(properties?: any) {
        (Object as any).assign(this, properties);
    }
}

export class User extends Base {
    user: string;
    firstname: string;
    surname: string;
    email: string;
    role: Role;
    active: boolean;

    getRole() {
        switch (this.role) {
            case Role.READ: {
                return "READ";
            }
            case Role.WRITE: {
                return "WRITE";
            }
            case Role.ADMIN: {
                return "ADMIN";
            }
            default : {
                return "READ";
            }
        }
    }  
}

export class Profile extends Base {
    user: User;
    apiKeys: ApiKey[];

    // take advantage of Object.assign
    // to initialize an instance of type Profile 
    // along with it's property user
    constructor(properties?: any) {
        super(properties);
        this.user = new User(properties.user);
    }
}
```

**ProfileService.ts**

```js
getProfile(): Observable <Profile> {
    return this.http.get<Profile>(this.profileUrl).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

**Component.ts**

```js
profile: Profile;
isProfileAvailable:boolean = false;

ngOnInit()
{
    this.settingsService.getProfile().subscribe(profileData => {
        // assuming that profileData looks like this:
        /*
        {
            user: {
                user: 'user',
                firstname: 'firstname',
                surname: 'surname',
                email: 'email',
                active: true
            }
        }
        */
        this.profile = new Profile(profileData);
        this.isProfileAvailable = true;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Blauharley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2401386/blauharley) answer worked like a charm.

However, since I have all my models in separate files, I had to export the Base class:

```js
export class Base {
    constructor(properties?: any) {
        (Object as any).assign(this, properties);
    }
}
```

Everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are not currently creating instances of your class, so the class method `getRole()` is not available. With `this.http.get<Profile>` you are just telling the compiler that what you expect from the API conforms to your class, it doesn't actually create instances of your class or subclass `User`.

You need to add a constructor to your classes with the properties and actually create **instances** of your class. Here's a simplified example:

```ts
export class User {
  role: string;

  constructor(role: string) {
    this.role = role;
  }

  getRole() {
    switch (this.role) {
      case 'READ': {
        return "READ";
      }
      case 'WRITE': {
        return "WRITE";
      }
      default: {
        return "READ";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then need to create an instance of your class to have access to class methods:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  let user = new User('WRITE');
  console.log(user.getRole());
}
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbrvqg?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Furthermore, if this would be the only method in your class that you need, I would just suggest to use interfaces instead and write a standalone function that checks the role instead of going through the hassle of creating instances of class. This is a very opinionated thing though, so if you want to use classes and class specific methods, you do need to go the above route. I just like to use interfaces personally :)